# View build.prop lines using textView in android studio

Tags: android

i'm creating a OTA APP [Over The Air] to make private updates to specific phones and i want , if are possible , to view in textView some build.prop lines like : ro.otaupdate.romid=3.2.0 , and in textView : 3.2.0 .
This are MainActivity code

```js
package splusteam.center.ota.ota_center;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Build;
import eu.chainfire.libsuperuser.Shell;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {



    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                (new StartUp()).setContext(v.getContext()).execute("recov");

            }
        });


    }




    private class StartUp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


        private Context context = null;
        boolean suAvailable = false;

        //Created by themakeinfo.com,Promote us !!!
        public StartUp setContext(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            suAvailable = Shell.SU.available();
            if (suAvailable) {

                // suResult = Shell.SU.run(new String[] {"cd data; ls"}); Shell.SU.run("reboot");
                switch (params[0]) {
                    case "reboot":
                        Shell.SU.run("reboot");
                        break;
                    case "recov":
                        Shell.SU.run("reboot recovery");
                        break;
                    case "shutdown":
                        Shell.SU.run("reboot -p");
                        break;
                    //case "sysui"   : Shell.SU.run("am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");break;
                    case "sysui":
                        Shell.SU.run("pkill com.android.systemui");
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone not Rooted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }


        private long[] params;



        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_view) {
                // Handle the camera action

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        public void btnSettings_OnClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void btnCheckUpdate_OnClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Updatecheck.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void btnRebootSystem_OnClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Reboot.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


}
```

Comment: And what is your question or problem exactly?

Comment: i want a code to display some values from build.prop in textView